# How to prevent a string property of my model to be converted to US format date in the View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, localization

I discovered something unexpected with my ASP.NET WebApp (Visual 2017 .NET Framework  4.6.1) in a production environment.
I have a model with a property `StringDato`, which is a STRING following the pattern `dd.mm.yyyy hh.mm.ss` (the german/european format).
Having faced some issues for parsing, I decided to work with strings for my dates, so there is no a single part of my code where I refer to a DateTime object.

In my development and testing environments (2 different IIS servers), `StringDato` is displayed as it should be. But in the production environment (a third IIS server) it always shows US formatted.

For example, `23.09.2017 17.45.00` will become `9/23/2017 5:45:00 PM`. This happens no matter what the browser is (IE/Edge/Chrome).

The browser is german/european configured, and so is the user's system. The only thing I don't know about yet is how my production server is configured.

I'm trying to get the logic here. Does it make sense to assume the server could "recognize" a string as a date because of its pattern, display it as a date, and format it according to it's config and not the user's settings? What else can I look at to fix this?

Comment: You presume a lot when you equate the german format with the european format. French, Brits, Germans, Greeks, and Polish all have their own quirks, just of a start, with various other nations following one or the other oftentimes with further quirks.

Comment: Also: the best option here **by far** will be to fix those parsing issues and use `DateTime` objects in your code.

Answer (score 0):

It´s simple. Keep Invariant Culture Info on Web.Config:

```
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <globalization uiCulture="de" culture="de-DE" />
  </system.web>
```

Comment: Both you and Joel seem to be the part of the answer.
You need the property to be a DateTime, otherwise the app. webconfig won't "recognize" it and apply the wanted culture.
If working with strings if required for some specific purposes (display and sorting in my case), it's possible provided the string  is a DateTime.ToString(). If not, the app webconfig will not apply its culture, whereas the IIS server config will.
Thank you.  (cant thumb you up because of profile)

Comment: You're right @GoupilSystem. I use the configuration with data annotation model: [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]